# Файл не сохраняется по введённому пути

Tags: python, ос

Итак, я пытаюсь сделать функцию сохранения mp3-файла с помощью библиотеки `os`. При указании пути скрипт должен сохранять файл по пути, однако файл всегда сохраняется туда же, где находится скрипт (сделал на всякий случай по умолчанию). Однако какой бы я путь ни указал (допустим G:\VScode projects\Random projects), он всегда сохраняет по пути где находится скрипт (G:\VScode projects\tts).

Код:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

class SoundGenerator:
    def __init__(self, filename, phrase, lang='en', path=None):
        self.phrase = phrase
        self.filename = filename
        self.lang = lang
        self.path = path

    def generate_sound(self):
        tts = gTTS(self.phrase, lang=self.lang)
        return tts

    def save_sound(self, path_and_file=None):
        if not self.filename:
            self.filename = 'default'

        if path_and_file is None:
            script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
            path_and_file = os.path.join(script_dir, self.filename + '.mp3')
        else:
            path_and_file = os.path.join(self.path, self.filename + '.mp3')

        tts = self.generate_sound()
        tts.save(path_and_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = input('Введите название файла : ')
    phrase = input('Введите фразу для озвучки (обязательно): ')
    path = input('Введите желаемый путь до файла (необязательно): ')
    lang = input('ru/en: ').lower()

    generated_sound = SoundGenerator(filename, phrase, lang, path)
    generated_sound.save_sound()
```

Comment: Вы сохранили указанный путь в `self.path`, который никак не используется, а вместо него вы используете `script_dir`

Comment: Да, проблема решилась: `script_dir` заменил на `self.path`, однако теперь путь для сохранения файла по умолчанию - это рабочая директория, а не директория со скриптом

Comment: Выведите отладочную информацию, да посмотрите какой путь у вас по итогу получается.

Comment: Ошибка была в том, что я сравнивал с `None`, в то время как, `self.path` был типа `str`. Добавив условие `self.path == ''` проблема решилась